# iTunes Test Account impossible to remove

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am being driven into madness by iTunes accounts.

I have been testing IAPs all day, with hosted content, I have switched onto my now third test account, as I need to do multiple tests on the initial purchases of some IAPs I have, and I need to recreate that initial purchase point to check my code.

So, I have named my accounts jan14test1@mydomain.com, jan14test2@mydomain.com etc etc.

I have logged out of test2, and logged into test3, made a purchase on test3 and am still logged into test3.

And now for the mind-break. When my app initially calls `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` , EVERY time, a pop up box appears asking for the password for the user account 'jan14test2@mydomain.com'. The account is pre-populated, even though I am still shown as logged in as jan14test3@mydomain.com in the Settings app from the dashboard.

If I enter the password nothing happens, if I click cancel, nothing happens, not a single delegate method fires. There is nothing in the transactions queue, no downloads pending, nothing.

I have soft reset the phone, cleared all settings, deleted the app, cleaned my build, deleted jan14test2@mydomain.com as a user in iTunesconnect, literally nothing I can do will purge this demon.

My IAPs all contain hosted content, I think the phone is stuck into thinking it is due a download, I have finish all transactions appropriately with; `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:payment];`

I am at a loss for ideas, my last resort is a Steve Jobs séance but I doubt that will be very fruitful either.

Comment: What's the "Settings app from the dashboard" ? Have you checked in e.g the app store app to see who you are actually logged in as ?

Comment: I may have meant to type springboard, I mean the Settings app, on the phone, the square grey cogs icon used to set time, accounts etc on the device. Yes, I checked, it says I am logged in as test3, occasionally this will spontaneously change to test2.

Comment: This is almost impossible to troubleshoot without seeing your setup, but I would suggest deleting the provisioning profile you are using and then recreating it to see if this fixes it. I would also open the app store app, scroll to the bottom, and check what account you are logged in with.

Comment: Also delete and re-install the app, clean the build and build folder.

Comment: I have deleted the app, cleaned my build on xcode, I have also used the 'Reset All Settings' option in Reset under General. I appreciate the difficulty in troubleshooting, thus my turning to stackoverflow after 5-6 hours of frustration.

Comment: the appstore app says I am logging in as jan14test3@mydomain.com, and yet jan14test2@ demands a login every time the app opens.

Comment: Ok - so does the app store say one thing and settings something different ? If so I think it's your device that's confused. Try hard restarting it ?

Comment: Settings and appstore say same thing, I have hard reset the phone. What is happening is purely isolated to my app, I would change the bundle id if I could but the app is currently on the store and I am working on an update.

Comment: Sounds like you definitely have a transaction stuck in the payment queue. Try moving [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; to the app delegate (if it's not there already).

Comment: Just in case... Have you tried logging off the user in Settings so the app will ask you for an Apple ID and a password, instead of already having a user in Settings?

Comment: Injuanj, I've answered you question above, I am logging out of the account completely, in Settings, App Store app, everywhere. The only solution was to Wipe my phone completely and set it up as a new phone.

Comment: It's as though a transaction was stuck in the queue for one account, but when I am logged in, i am logged in with another account, which cannot see that payment in the payment queue. Incredibly peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the transaction was stuck because the transaction with the first test account was not completed.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

Finishing that transaction allowed me to use other test accounts.